# PHP Double Variable Array Issue

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a variable stack in object form:

- $people->one
- $people->two
- $people->three
- $people->four

I also have an array of data that when applicable, I want to replace those values. The array has things like: Lets call the array $stats

- "two" => 1
- "four" => 14

What I have been trying to accomplish (and this was using the double variable, is replace the value in the original object stack with an updated value if in the array.

```
foreach ($stats as $key => $value) {    
    $data = "people->" . $key;
    $$data = "<strong>" . $$data .  "</strong>";
}
```

But, that just doesn't look like it should work, and isn't as clean as I would like it. Is there a better way to handle something like this?

Thanks for any help that can be provide.

^^^

Update:

Basically I am trying to wrap  around a variable, if the variable shows up in the array. And, then have it print like the original value, except with the  wrapped around it.

Comment: I have updated the top to where there are not two $value sets. That was dumb on my part.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arrayvariable as $key => $val) {    
    $value->$key = "<strong>" . $value->$key .  "</strong>";
}
```

I suspect you meant

```
$$data = "<strong>" . $value .  "</strong>";
```

in your question, which would translate to

```
$value->$key = "<strong>" . $val .  "</strong>";
```

Comment: When I try something like $people->$key = "<strong>" . $people->$key .  "</strong>"; It isn't setting that data point to where I can print it with the orignal $people->two (with the new <strong> wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

```
$value        = new stdClass();
$value->one   = 1;
$value->two   = 2;
$value->three = 3;
$value->four  = 4;

$arr          = array();
$arr['one']   = 11;
$arr['four']  = 14;

foreach($value as $key => &$val){
    if(isset($arr[$key])) {
        $val = $arr[$key];
    }
}

var_dump($value); // object(stdClass)#1 (4) { ["one"]=> int(11) ["two"]=> int(2) ["three"]=> int(3) ["four"]=> &int(14) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$obj` is your object, you can do this.

```
$key = 'four';
echo $obj->$key;
```